# Python QuasarDB connection refused

Tags: python, docker

I'm following QuasarDB guide here: https://doc.quasar.ai/master/primer.html

```
> docker run -d --name qdb-server bureau14/qdb
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
6b28287a871b   bureau14/qdb   "/opt/qdb/scripts/qd…"   32 minutes ago   Up 31 minutes   2836-2837/tcp, 3836/tcp   qdb-server
```

This is the example code to run QuasarDB:

```
import quasardb

# connecting, default port is 2836
c = quasardb.Cluster("qdb://127.0.0.1:2836")
# creating a timeseries object
my_ts = c.ts("stocks")
# creating the timeseries in the database
# it will throw an error if the timeseries already exist
my_ts.create([quasardb.ColumnInfo(quasardb.ColumnType.Double, "close")])
```

---

```
python3 primer.py
  File "/home/dtl/Documents/qdb/primer.py", line 5, in <module>
    c = quasardb.Cluster("qdb://127.0.0.1:2836")
quasardb.quasardb.Error: at qdb_connect: Connection refused.
```

What might cause `Connection refused` in this case? The example doesn't include this scenario.

Edit: Stackoverflow doesn't have tag `quasardb` :\

Comment: Stack overflow currently doesn't have tag for quasardb is because it's a relatively new technology https://github.com/bureau14 . I encountered the same issue trying to reproduce guide in the [documentation](https://doc.quasar.ai/master/primer.html). My guess is that the `docker run` command doesn't expose the port to localhost . I think you should check with the devs at https://github.com/bureau14/qdb-api-python or through customer support https://doc.quasar.ai/master/support/contact.html

Comment: Can you share the command used to run the python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish the port in docker run command
`docker run -p 2836:2836 -d --name qdb-server bureau14/qdb`